# How to pass result of command within While Loop in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script which will wait for the completion of a task that will occur across a few Windows Server reboots.  There is a PowerShell command to check for the status of the operation with a field called Status.  On completion the value of Status is "Finished". Why does this snippet not work, instead of not executing the while loop it executes the code:

```
while ( (Get-WssConfigurationStatus | select Status) -ne "Finished" ) {
  Write-Host "Waiting for WSS Configuration to complete"
  sleep -seconds 60
}
```

If you are interested this is part of a wider Packer script to install Windows Server Essentials role on 2012R2.

Thanks in advance,
Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This test script works here:

```
while ( (Get-Service audiosrv).Status -ne "Finished" ) {
  Write-Host (get-date) "Waiting for WSS Configuration to complete"
  sleep -seconds 60
}
```

So change your first line to:

```
while ( (Get-WssConfigurationStatus).Status -ne "Finished" ) {
```

Comment: That works perfectly.  I had forgotten about this particular syntax.  Thanks, Al